# Django rest framework in register and login api

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**I am a beginner in Django**

[Git Repo](https://github.com/brijesh-kalkani/LoginAPI)

I was creating the register and login API, and I have also created the register API, and there is nothing wrong with that, but I did not know anything about the login API so I got an error, in my opinion, **serializers.py** and There is a slight error in the **views.py**, please tell me the error so I know where my error is.

> File "/Users/sierra/Courses/LoginAPI/form/serializers.py",line 14
>
> if Account.objects.filter(email=email,password=password).exists() :
> TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentationBlockquote

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from form.models import Account

# from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class LoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['email', 'password',]

        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

        if Account.objects.filter(email=email,password=password).exists() :
            return True

        return False

    # def validate(self, data):
    #   password = data.get('password')
    #   email = data.get('email')


    # def username_present(email,password):




class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'password2']
        extra_kwargs = {
                'password': {'write_only': True},
        }


    def save(self):

        account = Account(
                    email=self.validated_data['email'],
                    username=self.validated_data['username']
                )
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords must match.'})
        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()
        return account
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from form.serializers import RegistrationSerializer


@api_view(['POST', ])
def registration_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            account = serializer.save()
            data['response'] = 'successfully registered new user.'
            data['email'] = account.email
            data['username'] = account.username
        else:
            data = serializer.errors
        return Response(data)

@api_view(['POST,'])
def login_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            date['response'] = 'User successfully Login'
        else:
            data['response'] = 'You have entered an invalid username or password'
        return Response(data)
```

Comment: It says incorrect indentation, try [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_python_formatter.htm) to format your code and run again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as the error says, there's a problem with the indentation on line 14.
indentations in python must by using tabs not spaces, so clear the spaces before the if condition to the very first of the line and give it **tabs** till it reaches the right indentation.

P.S: if it still gives you same error, try with the previous line.

Comment: @LogwinTech same line?

Comment: try with every line in Meta class to just remove all indentations before  the line to the very first, then indent using tabs to the needed indentation.

Comment: @LogwinTech use this editor https://codebeautify.org/python-formatter-beautifier please

Comment: set indentation to 4.

Comment: i guess i knew where the problem is, you are trying to return from a class which is wrong .. the condition with its returns must be in a function not class @LogwinTech

Comment: i think you should try remove the condition and returns from the class to a function called exists or something.

Answer (score 1):

This is proper solution of your question:-

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.exceptions import NotAuthenticated
from .models import register

class LoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = register
    fields = ['username', 'password',]
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

def validate(self, data):
    username = data.get("username", None)
    password = data.get("password", None)
    if register.objects.filter(username=username).filter(password=password).first():
        return True
    raise NotAuthenticated
```

**Views.py**

```
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
import utils.response_handler as rh
from .serializers import LoginSerializer

class loginview(RetrieveAPIView):
    def post(self, request):
        username=request.data.get('username')
        serializer = LoginSerializer(self,data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            r=rh.ResponseMsg(data={
                "username":username,
            },msg="Login Successfully",error=False)
            return Response(r.response)
```